# Issue with height:auto and Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to setup a section of my page with 3 columns using Flexbox.

The 3 columns are set up just fine, the issue I am having is with the section1 div not being as tall as the children elements.

I have tried `height: auto`, `height:100%`, `overflow: auto`, `overflow:visible`, etc. The only time the section1 div changes height is when I specifically state a pixel height. It seems as though the flexbox items are acting as floats so I tried a `clear:both` to no avail.

I have searched both stackoverflow and other sites and have not found an answer which leads me to believe it is something I am doing wrong with flexbox.

```css
body {
  background: lightgrey;
}
.body {
  position: relative;
  width: 75% /* 747.75px */;
  margin: auto;
  top: -3.5em;
  background-color: white;
  border-top: 3px solid #ff8400;
}
.top-border {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 2em;
  border-top: 1px solid #eef3f0;
  width: 95%;
  left: 2.5%;
}
.section1 {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  top: 5em;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="top-border"></div>
  <div class="section1">
    <div class="what-i-do">
      <img class="what-i-do-icon" src="images/what-i-do.png" />
      <h1 class="what-i-do-title">What I Do</h1>
      <p class="what-i-do-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam semper quam arcu,
        a consequat tellus cursus vel. Vivamus lacus massa, feugiat non malesuada sed, efficitur eu elit. </p>
      <p class="view-more-btn">View More</p>
    </div>
    <div class="development">
      <img class="development-icon" src="images/development.png" />
      <h1 class="development-title">Development</h1>
      <p class="development-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam semper quam arcu,
        a consequat tellus cursus vel. Vivamus lacus massa, feugiat non malesuada sed, efficitur eu elit. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="design">
      <img class="design-icon" src="images/design.png" />
      <h1 class="design-title">Design</h1>
      <p class="design-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam semper quam arcu, a
        consequat tellus cursus vel. Vivamus lacus massa, feugiat non malesuada sed, efficitur eu elit. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you have `position: relative;` on all elements?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. `height:auto` does nothing in flexbox (usually) and the height of the `section1` **does** change when re-sizing the screen - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/mVEGxw

Comment: You can do something like this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/413/, use media queries instead of `word-break: break-all;`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/L3w3uwvj/embedded/result/

Comment: If you look on that jsfiddle, you can see that the white background does not stretch to the full height of the paragraphs. I'm sorry if I didn't make that clear.

Comment: Sure it does if you take out all the odd positioning you have in there. - https://jsfiddle.net/L3w3uwvj/3/

Comment: Unfortunately this is only a snippet of the actual code. The odd positioning is somewhat important to the overall layout.

Comment: I figured out the issue. Instead of using top for the top-border div I used margin-top.

Comment: If you're using that much positioning..you're doing it wrong. Positioning should only be used for specific effects not general layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Relative positioning](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#relative-positioning)

> Once a box has been laid out according to the [normal flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#normal-flow) or
>   floated, it may be shifted relative to this position. This is called
>   *relative positioning*. Offsetting a box (B1) in this way has no effect on the box (B2) that follows: B2 is given a position as if B1
>   were not offset and B2 is not re-positioned after B1's offset is
>   applied. This implies that relative positioning may cause boxes to
>   overlap.

Here you don't want to shift a single box, you want it to push following content too. Then, you should use [margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties) for that.

```css
body {
  background: lightgrey;
}
.body {
  width: 75% /* 747.75px */;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: -3.5em;
  background-color: white;
  border-top: 3px solid #ff8400;
}
.top-border {
  top: 2em;
  border-top: 1px solid #eef3f0;
  width: 95%;
  margin-left: 2.5%;
}
.section1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="top-border"></div>
  <div class="section1">
    <div class="what-i-do">
      <img class="what-i-do-icon" src="images/what-i-do.png" />
      <h1 class="what-i-do-title">What I Do</h1>
      <p class="what-i-do-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam semper quam arcu,
        a consequat tellus cursus vel. Vivamus lacus massa, feugiat non malesuada sed, efficitur eu elit. </p>
      <p class="view-more-btn">View More</p>
    </div>
    <div class="development">
      <img class="development-icon" src="images/development.png" />
      <h1 class="development-title">Development</h1>
      <p class="development-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam semper quam arcu,
        a consequat tellus cursus vel. Vivamus lacus massa, feugiat non malesuada sed, efficitur eu elit. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="design">
      <img class="design-icon" src="images/design.png" />
      <h1 class="design-title">Design</h1>
      <p class="design-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam semper quam arcu, a
        consequat tellus cursus vel. Vivamus lacus massa, feugiat non malesuada sed, efficitur eu elit. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```